# How to check database permission with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the easiest was to check with Entity Framework Core if the user from the connection string has write access to the database?
I'd like to check this already while starting up the application instead of getting an exception later because of missing permissions.
E.g. in MSSQL it is possible to check with this statement `SELECT isnull(has_perms_by_name('dbo.tablename', 'OBJECT', 'INSERT'), 0)`

Is there a better way than to manually do it this way in .NET? Because otherwise I need to check this for MariaDB separately.
Or should I try a to do an insert, and catch the exception or otherwise roll it back?

Comment: As far as I know - there is no better way than what you described (raw sql statement).

Comment: You could abstract it away in the database itself by adding a little procedure/function like `CanWrite`.